# Is AsParallel().ForAll reliable

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, parallel.foreach, reliability

I have query with AsParallel().ForAll is sometimes skipping some records and sometimes returning null records in my case.

I am not sure for this is the exact reason for this.
Is the mechanism for parellal for in .Net reliable?

Edit:
Sample code

```
var collection=.. Collection from database
var processedCollection=...
collection.Where(h => h.Id == id).AsParallel().ForAll(h =>
{
    var processedCollectionItem = ....logic to process the item
    processedCollectionItem.Where(c=>c.....).AsParallel().ForAll(c =>
    {
        //logic to process the records
    });
    processedCollection.Add(processedCollectionItem);
});
```

Comment: I strongly suspect that it's your *usage* of it that's at fault, not the BCL. Can you post a short but complete program demonstrating the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding stuff to a collection in a parallel loop, it would probably be better to let the framework handle building the collection.

Example:

```
var processedCollection = collection
    .Where(h => h.Id == id)
    .AsParallel()
    .Select(h => ProcessItem(h))
    .ToArray();
```

In ProcessItem the processing would occur. Doing that in parallel seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

I guess `processedCollection` is a collection that is not thread safe (probably a simple generic list?).

A simple solution is to use a lock:

```
lock (processedCollection) // or better use a dedicated lock object
{
    processedCollection.Add(processedCollectionItem);
}
```

or use a thread safe collection like a `ConcurrentBag<>`.

Comment: Yes the processedCollection is simple generic list.